# javascript comparing two values

Tags: javascript, html

In Js how do I compare two values. i have got three buttons that each generate a number between `1` and `3`.

I want to compare the number they output with the  number of the `button`, for example the first button could be `1`, the second `2`, the third `3`.

If the number generated by the button is the same as 2, it says its a draw.

```
function Random()
{
    var result = display.innerHTML = Math.floor((Math.random() * 3) + 1);
}
```

HTML Code:

```
<form>
    <input id="rock"     type="button" onclick="Random()" value="Rock"     />
    <input id="paper"    type="button" onclick="Random()" value="Paper"    />
    <input id="scissors" type="button" onclick="Random()" value="Scissors" />
</form>
```

Comment: Maybe the `<` and `==` operators could be of use.

Comment: Whats your `buttons` code? Please put them here

Comment: <form>
  <input id="rock" type="button" onclick="Random()" value="Rock"/>
  <input id="paper" type="button" onclick="Random()" value="Paper"/>
  <input id="scissors" type="button" onclick="Random()" value="Scissors"/>
</form>

Comment: the buttons do not have numerical values, however they represent a number, therefore if the user presses rock, and the number generated by the computer is 1, its a draw because rock and rock is a draw.

Comment: Hoe do computer generate?  you have to generate it.

Answer (score 2):

`===` is used to be **strict comparison operator**

```
var display = document.getElementById("respective selector ID");
var result = parseInt(display.innerHTML) === Math.floor((Math.random() * 3) + 1);
```

**UPDATES:**

Since you updated your question, here

**HTML:**

```
 <form>
        <input id="rock" type="button" onclick="Random(this.id)" value="1" />
        <input id="paper" type="button" onclick="Random(this.id)" value="2" />
        <input id="scissors" type="button" onclick="Random(this.id)" value="3" />
    </form>
    <span id="show"></span>
```

**JS:**

```
function Random(id) {
    var display= parseInt(document.getElementById(id).value); 
    if( display === Math.floor((Math.random() * 3) + 1)){
        document.getElementById('show').innerHTML = "EQUAL";
    }
    else{
          document.getElementById('show').innerHTML = "NOT EQUAL";
    }
}
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/tMRZb/3/)

(1) The **innerHTML/value** always return `string` datatype, so I'hv used `.parseInt()`
(2) `onclick="Random(this.id)"` using this I'm passing the id of the button.

Hope you understand.

Answer (score 1):

You can compare equality with `==` or `===`.

Please read about javascript's Comparison [operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators)

And understand the need and importance of both `==` and `===` they are used differently.

```
var x = 5, y = 10;
x === y //false
x === x //true
x == "5" //true
x === "5" //false
x < y //true
x > y // false
```

Answer (score 0):

== is compare operator

```
function Random()
{
    var result = display.innerHTML == Math.floor((Math.random() * 3) + 1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I copied some part from your previous question regarding the same issue

```
<input id="rock" type="button" onclick="Random(0)" value="Rock"/>
<input id="paper" type="button" onclick="Random(1)" value="Paper"/>
<input id="scissors" type="button" onclick="Random(2)"  value="Scissors"/>
<br />
<span id="display"></span>
```

Then

```
function Random(choice) {
    var system = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3);
    display.innerHTML = system == choice ? 'draw' : system;
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/tMRZb/)

Comment: var system = Math.floor(Math.random()* 3);,

Comment: can you explain this code please    display.innerHTML = system == choice ? 'draw' : system;  what does the ? and the : do?

Comment: @WerErew It is called **ternary operator(condition? if block : else block)**.  used to be an inline *if.. else..* statement.

Answer (score 0):

Or, if you prefer to work with jQuery, you could use this :

```
<button id="button_1" onclick="myRandom('button_1')">1</button>
<button id="button_2" onclick="myRandom('button_2')">2</button>
<button id="button_3" onclick="myRandom('button_3')">3</button>
```

And in javascript:

```
function myRandom(id) {
    a = Math.floor((Math.random() * 3) + 1);
    if ($("#" + id).html() == a)
        alert("Button " + $("#" + id).html() + " is Match. Generated value is " + a + ".");
    else
        alert("Button " + $("#" + id).html() + " is not Match. Generated value is " + a + ".");
}
```

[Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/dirgagautama/ae8jX/1/).

Answer (score 0):

Usually you would use the `==` operator, if you want a strict comparison, use `===`.

e.g.

```
if(a == b)
{/*if true*/}
```

Above, if a is a `string` with that value of 1 and b is an `int` with the value of 1, it will evaluate as true.

but if you do the following:

```
if(a === b)
{/*if true*/}
```

both a and b have to be either `int` of `string`.

In your case, just `==` will work fine.